# Google Maps Markers - how to get these to show please

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I have my fully functioning map although am not sure why I can't get any markers or clusters to come in on this? The JS code I have is below:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: { lat: 51.40219, lng: -0.16890 }
    });

    var labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    
  }

//Coordinates for the various Memorials and Cemetries listed for the corresponding Hero that will be marked on the map.
// I used https://codepen.io/ahmadawais/pen/NQdWQx?editors=1010 to see how to do the below with the locations as this way it will show with the names of the memorials or cemeteries
var locations = [
  ['Private Richard Spearink - St Souplet British Cemetery', { lat: 50.05484, lng: 3.52440 }, 1],
  ['Private Frederick Spearink - Mitcham War Memorial', { lat: 51.40219, lng: -0.16890 }, 2],
  ['Private Frederick Spearink - Helles Memorial', { lat: 40.04597, lng: 26.17921}, 2]
];

var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length]
  });
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, { imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m' });
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I either need to add or remove please as I'm not sure why this isn't working?

Comment: There are 2 issues: 1. the lat/lng coordinates are not passed in correctly (`location` is not a `LatLngLiteral`), 2. the markers array and  markerClusterer initialization is outside of the `initMap` function, so will run before the map is initialized, see [the example in the Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering).  [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1o9qwrud/3/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not correctly passing in your latitude and longitude for your markers.

Your `locations` array is an array of fixed-length arrays ("tuples"), the second of which is an object of `lat` and `lng` that matches [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral). That's the right value for [`position` in MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.position), but in your `locations.map` you're passing `location`, which here is the entire tuple.

Because each entry is not a `location`, I've renamed `location` to `locationTuple`; the names don't matter to the code, but it does make it clearer that **you'll need to use `locationTuple[1]` (or `location[1]`) to refer to your value for `position`**. At that point you can also use the labels as `locationTuple[0]` rather than picking an arbitrary letter.

```js
var locations = [
  ['Private Richard Spearink - St Souplet British Cemetery', { lat: 50.05484, lng: 3.52440 }, 1],
  ['Private Frederick Spearink - Mitcham War Memorial', { lat: 51.40219, lng: -0.16890 }, 2],
  ['Private Frederick Spearink - Helles Memorial', { lat: 40.04597, lng: 26.17921}, 2]
];

var markers = locations.map(function(locationTuple, i) {   // rename
  return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: locationTuple[1],                          // rename + add index 1
      label: locationTuple[0]                              // rename + add index 0
  });
});
```

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome! If this solved your problem, remember to [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), which marks the question as solved and gives you a small rep bonus.